Navbar/Subnav active class in react
so lately I'm just testing out and learning routing using react-router-dom and I did make a Navbar with Subnav and its working and changing on navigation.
I have a problem with active-nav class on the link where subnav is.
Here is how I want it:

clicking any sublinks activates the class on the parent link in this case: Services +

I know that it doesnt activates because the pathname isnt matching, but cant figure it out.
Also if theres a better way to do this I'm more than happy to learn.
Heres Navbar.js:
import { Link, useMatch, useResolvedPath } from "react-router-dom"
import React, { useState } from "react"
import './App.css';


export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <NavbarLink to="/">Home</NavbarLink>
                <NavbarLink to="/a-word">A word</NavbarLink>
                <NavbarLink to="/services" sublinks={[
                    {to: "/services/bread", label: "Bread" },
                    {to: "/services/carrot", label: "Carrot" }
                ]}>Services +</NavbarLink>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    )
}

function NavbarLink({ to, children, sublinks }) {
    const resolvedPath = useResolvedPath(to);
    const isActive = useMatch({ path: resolvedPath.pathname, exact: true });
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);


    return (
        <li>
            <Link to={to} className={isActive ? "active-nav" : ""} onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
                {children}
            </Link>
            {sublinks && isShown && (
                <ul onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
                    {sublinks.map((sublink, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <Link to={sublink.to}>{sublink.label}</Link>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </li>
    );
}



